# How to send Laravel Mail using Outlook?

Tags: laravel, laravel-mail

I want to send mail when user registred but i got this error.

```
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "*****" using 2 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful ". Authenticator NTLM returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful ".
```

How can i solve this?

Here is my mail configuration :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=*****
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=****
MAIL_PASSWORD=****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=covid19@sante.gouv.dj
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is for Office 365 (since you tagged your question as "outlook" even though it has nothing to do with Outlook), then  you need to use TLS on port 587 to connect to smtp.office365.com. Authentication is OAuth2.

Comment: Also if i remember correctly he needs to allow third party programs inside his outlook account  -> https://help.protectedtrust.com/setup-smtp-with-office-365